# React Context API Provider not updating in second location in app

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am building a form that separates into multiple tabs.  I am using the React Context API to capture the state of my form inputs and set the state in the Provider.  This comes through fine in my Consumer at the form input location.  However, I also have a view in the form, in the last tab, that I can review the input of the form in all steps. 
The Provider in that location only shows the default state values in React Dev Tools and so, can not update the Consumer. 
I'm not sure why the state in the second instantiation of the Provider is not being updated to pass as props to the review section.  I have exported the `createContext()` from the provider and am importing it into my review section Consumer and my form input section Consumer.
Heres some code:

**Provider:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import moment from 'moment';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const defaultDateState = moment();

const daysWeek = [
    {name: 'All'},
    {name: 'Sunday'},
    {name: 'Monday'},
    {name: 'Tuesday'},
    {name: 'Wednesday'},
    {name: 'Thursday'},
    {name: 'Friday'},
    {name: 'Saturday'}
];
const descMaxChars = 512;

export const BasicContext = React.createContext();

class BasicInfoProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        basicDesc: null,
        startDate: defaultDateState,
        endDate: defaultDateState,
        daysOfWeek: null,
        dayWeek: [],
        dayWeekOptions: daysWeek,
        descCharsLeft: descMaxChars,
    };

    //handle dates
    handleChangeStart = (date) => {
        console.log(date);
        this.setState({
          startDate: date
        });
      }

      handleChangeEnd = (date) => {
        this.setState({
          endDate: date
        });
      }


    handleChangeDesc = (e) => {
        var input = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            basicDesc: input,
            descCharsLeft: descMaxChars - input.length
        });
    }

    handleDaysWeek = (e) => {
        console.log('days week selection', e.target.value)
        const daySelection = e.target.value;
        let daySelectionArr;
        if(this.state.dayWeek.indexOf(daySelection) > -1) {
            daySelectionArr = this.state.dayWeek.filter(s => s !== daySelection)
        } else {
            daySelectionArr = [...this.state.dayWeek, daySelection];
        }
        this.setState({ dayWeek: daySelectionArr });
    }


    render(){
       return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <BasicContext.Provider value={{
                    state: this.state,
                    actions: {
                        handleChangeDesc: this.handleChangeDesc,
                        handleChangeEnd: this.handleChangeEnd,
                        handleChangeStart: this.handleChangeStart,
                        handleDaysWeek: this.handleDaysWeek
                    },
                }}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </BasicContext.Provider> 
            </React.Fragment>

       )
    }
}

export const contextTypes = {
        basicDesc: PropTypes.string,
        startDate: PropTypes.number,
        endDate: PropTypes.number,
        daysOfWeek: PropTypes.string,
        dayWeek: PropTypes.array,
        dayWeekOptions: PropTypes.array,
        descCharsLeft: PropTypes.number,
}

export default BasicInfoProvider;
```

**Form Input Consumer:**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import DateElement from "../DateElement";
import { Button, ButtonToolbar, FormGroup, ControlLabel, Checkbox, FormControl, HelpBlock, Modal, Glyphicon } from "react-bootstrap";
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { BasicContext, contextTypes } from './BasicInfoProvider';
import {getContext} from '../../utilities/GetContext';

import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

class BasicInfoForm extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <section className="basic-info-section">
                <BasicContext.Consumer >
                    {({state, actions}) => (
                    <React.Fragment>
                        <div className="row">
                            <FormGroup
                                controlId="desc-field"
                            >
                                <h3>Description</h3>
                                <FormControl
                                    type="textarea"
                                    value={state.basicDesc}
                                    placeholder="Enter Your Description Here"
                                    onChange={actions.handleChangeDesc}
                                    maxLength="512"
                                />
                                <FormControl.Feedback />
                                <HelpBlock>Characters left: {state.descCharsLeft}</HelpBlock>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </div>

                     <hr/>

                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="date-picker-duo col-sm-6">
                                <div className="col-xs-6">
                                    <h3>Start Date</h3>
                                    <DatePicker
                                    inline
                                    selected={state.startDate}
                                    selectsStart
                                    onChange={actions.handleChangeStart} 
                                    placeholderText='Click to select a date'
                                    className="start-date-field"
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-xs-6">
                                    <h3>End Date</h3>
                                    <DatePicker
                                    inline
                                    selected={state.endDate}
                                    selectsend
                                    onChange={actions.handleChangeEnd} 
                                    placeholderText='Click to select a date'
                                    className="end-date-field"
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <FormGroup bsClass="col-sm-6" controlId="formControlsSelectMultiple">
                                <h3 className="days-checkbox-title">Days of the Week</h3>
                                {state.dayWeekOptions.map((day) => {
                                    return(
                                        <div className="weekday-checkbox col-xs-3">
                                            <input 
                                                value={day.name}
                                                onChange={actions.handleDaysWeek} 
                                                type="checkbox" 
                                                id={day.name}
                                                key={day.name} />
                                            <label htmlFor={day.name}>{day.name}</label>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })}

                            </FormGroup>

                        </div>
                    </React.Fragment>
                    )}
                </BasicContext.Consumer>

                </section>
            );
    }
};

export default BasicInfoForm = getContext(contextTypes)(BasicInfoForm);
```

**The Review Section Consumer**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BasicContext, contextTypes } from './BasicInfoProvider';
import {getContext} from '../../utilities/GetContext';

const finalReview = (props) => {
    return(
        <div className="row">
            <h2>So you're all done with your new Promotion?</h2>

            <p>Take another look at what you're about to submit and if you like how it looks, send it on through!</p>
            <div className="well">

                <header className="review-section-header">
                    <h3>Basic Info </h3> 
                    <span className="review-edit" onClick={() => this.handleTabSelect(1)}>Edit Section</span>
                </header>
                <BasicContext.Consumer >
                    {({state}) => (
                <div className="review-group">
                    <p>
                        <span className="review-title">Description: </span> 
                        <span className="review-value">{state.basicDesc}</span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <span className="review-title">Promotion Start Date: </span> 
                        <span className="review-value">{state.startDate.toString()}</span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <span className="review-title">Promotion End Date: </span> 
                        <span className="review-value">{state.endDate.toString()}</span>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <span className="review-title">Promotion Days of the Week: </span> 
                        <span className="review-value"> 
                            {state.dayWeek.map((day) => {
                                return( `${day}, `)
                            })}
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                )}
                </BasicContext.Consumer>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const FinalReview = getContext(contextTypes)(finalReview);

export default FinalReview;
```

`getContext` is just a simple HOC that I'm passing the ContextTypes in with. 
`BasicInfoForm` is a child component of the form that exists in a tab inside the form, but the provider is going directly to it, so I think that the tabs are irrelevant.

My expectation is that the `BasicInfoProvider` will update when the `BasicInfoForm` invokes the passed in functions and that update will be reflected everywhere the `BasicInfoProvider` is used, but that is not happening when it is used for the `FinalReview` component